# How can I fix this error: provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server (ASP.NET)?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

I recently tried to connect my ASP.NET Core app to SQL Server via connected services. Unfortunately, after many attempts, I kept getting this error message (unfortunately it is in German):

[image: error message]

Translation

> Network-related or instance-specific error when connecting to SQL Server. The server was not found or is inaccessible. Check that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server allows remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Connection to SQL Server could not be opened)

Comment: What's your SQL Server connection string? You are trying to connect using named pipes but maybe can connect only using the network port.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why am I getting "Cannot Connect to Server - A network-related or instance-specific error"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18060667/why-am-i-getting-cannot-connect-to-server-a-network-related-or-instance-speci) There are many possible reasons why this may happen. Please check all relevant points in that link: Remote connections allowed? TCP turned on? Is SQL Server service started? Is it a named instance, if so do you have the instance name in the connection string, is the correct port open, is SQL Browser started? Is a firewall blocking the connection?